# Angular - Why does my fetch url from json file not working

Tags: node.js, json, angular, http

I am just starting out practicing angular and ran into some problems with my code. I have created mock data and placed it into a db.json file to use on my web app. On my web app I have 2 pages that get routed home page(page that displays grid) and details page that uses the id data to display information related that id(gets the id from url). My home page works displays all the data that it gets from the json file. My details page comes up blank and doesn't display anything even though in my url it says the id number. I have pictures and code  snippets below.

My home page:
[image]

My details page:
URL: localhost:4200/Details/0
[image]

code for home page

```
async getAllCharacters(): Promise<Info[]> {
const data = await fetch(this.url);
return await data.json() ?? [];
```

}

```
constructor() {
this.characterService.getAllCharacters().then((characterInfoList: Info[]) => {
  this.characterInfoList = characterInfoList;
});
```

}

code that displays details page

```
async getCharacterById(id: Number): Promise<Info | undefined> {
const data = await fetch(`${this.url}/${id}`);
return await data.json() ?? {};
```

}

```
constructor() {
const characterInfoId = Number(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
this.characterService.getCharacterById(characterInfoId).then(characterInfo => {
  this.characterInfo = characterInfo;
});
```

}

I have been stuck on this and not sure why the home page would work but the details page doesn't. If someone can help and explain the issue that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it possible for a stackblitz with the issue replicated. or if its a open github repository, could you share the details of the same!

Comment: @NarenMurali you want the github link to my project? Sorry not sure what you are asking

Comment: yes since the code is incomplete and the issue cant be debugged effectively!

Comment: @NarenMurali https://github.com/TaricDF/Starter-Page